# reflections of a point around the sides of a triangle: the area stays constant

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, reflection

Given a triangle $\Delta ABC$ and a point $P$, we define $P_A, P_B, P_C$ as the reflections of $P$ around $BC, AC, AB$ respectively. 
Now, $P_A, P_B, P_C$ are collinear **if and only if** $P\in(ABC)$. **(1)**

[image]

Furthermore, define $c$ to be a circle concentric with $(ABC)$, i.e. $c$ has the circumcenter of $\Delta ABC$ as its center. 
Then $A_{\Delta ABC}$ stays invariable as $P$ varies along $c$. **(2)**

[image]

I managed to prove (1) (using a homothety of the Simson line), but how can you prove (2)?
I'm especially interested in a synthetic proof.

Comment: See https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/PedalTriangle.shtml

Comment: The second part follows from taking a homothety centred at $P$ with ratio $\frac{1}{2}$ and Euler's Pedal Triangle Theorem.

Comment: @Anubhab Ghosal Very clever ! (in the same spirit of what OP has done by homothetising Simson line). Please transform your two comments into a complete answer. I will be very happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $PP_A\cap BC=\{A_1\}$, $PP_B\cap AC=\{B_1\}$ and $PP_C\cap AB=\{C_1\}.$

Thus, quadrilaterals $AC_1PB_1$, $CA_1B_1P$ and $BC_1PA_1$ are cyclic.

Now, let $P_A,$ $P_B$ and $P_C$ are collinear.

Thus, since $B_1C_1||P_BP_C$ and $B_1A_1||P_BP_A,$ we see that $A_1,$ $B_1$ and $C_1$ are collinear and we obtain:
$$\measuredangle PAC=\measuredangle PC_1B_1=\measuredangle PBA_1=\measuredangle PBC,$$ which says that $PABC$ is cyclic.

Now, if $PABC$ is cyclic and $P$ is placed on the arc $AC$,

which without a point $B$, so by the same way we obtain:
$$\measuredangle PC_1B_1=\measuredangle PBC$$ and $$\measuredangle PA_1B_1=\measuredangle PBA,$$
which says that $$\measuredangle PC_1B_1+\measuredangle PA_1B_1=\measuredangle ABC=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle A_1PC_1$$ and we got that $A_1,$ $B_1$ and $C_1$ are collinear,

which gives that $P_A,$ $P_B$ and $P_C$ are collinear and we are done!